# default.aspx background image

Tags: xhtml, silverlight-4.0

I have a simple question probablly easy for someone...

I want to change de default.aspx background from white to a simple IMAGE (.jpg) and i couldnt do this adding :

< param name="background" value="/images/fondo.jpg"  >

What`s the right ay to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You've included the silverlight-4.0 tag because ...?

Answer (score 2):

```
<body background=BackgroundImage>
```

In your case,

```
body background="/images/fondo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a Background mark to the Body...

Here is the code:

body>

form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">

```
div id="silverlightControlHost">

    object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="100%" height="100%">

        param name="source" value="ClientBin/CCARS.Client.xap" />


        param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />


        param name="background" value="white" />
        param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
        param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        param name="splashscreensource" value="Splash.xaml" />
        param name="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" value="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" />
        param name="onSourceDownloadComplete" value="onSourceDownloadCompleted" />
        a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration: none">
            img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        /a>
    /object>
    iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
        border: 0px"></iframe>
/div>
/form>
```

/body>

Comment: Is this an answer to you question?  If not please delete this answer.  Move this additional information to your question using the edit function.  Take some time to read the FAQ